# How to merge 2 losses in a reasonable ratio

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions, gradient

my question is pretty basic, but I can't find many resources online about this.

Say we have two losses for a model, for example a pix2pix GAN, which for those who are not familiar with it, for the generator, has 2 losses:
$$
L_{gen} = L_{discriminator} + \lambda L_{rconstruction}
$$
where $L_{discriminator}$ is for example mean squared error and $L_{rconstruction}$ is binary crossentropy

Now, I would like to know if there is a way to balance those 2 losses, in other words, how to choose $\lambda$

I'm asking this because I quite sure that makes no sense to compare the actual value of the losses, but makes maybe sense to compare the gradient.
However, at that point, i don't know which gradient (or, with respect to which weight/layer) I should consider.

My question comes from the fact that I would like to know which $\lambda$ gives more importance to the reconstruction wrt the discriminator, and which value of$\lambda$ gives more importance to the discriminator than to the reconstruction

Comment: The closer $\lambda$ is to $0$, the more we prioritize discrimination, and the closer it is to $\infty$, the more we prioritize reconstruction.

Comment: @JohnMadden yes, of course, I was looking for a more specific answer, maybe a confidence interval ahah

Comment: Let the rest of us know if you find one :) in practice, people would try different $\lambda$'s and pick the one that makes the prettiest pictures.

Comment: @JohnMadden ahah yes, that was what I was looking to avoid, because it's pretty computational expensive, and seems to be a math-related problem, so maybe there are good guesses (wrt something like "guess the number of layers")

Comment: You could try weighing them equally by choosing $\lambda=\frac{||g_{d}||_2}{||g_{r}||_2}$ where $g_d$ is a gradient of the first term and $g_r$ the second ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @JohnMadden  but the gradient wrt to what? to all the weights?

Comment: Yes. But the real question is: which gradient? The first one at the very beginning of training? Update it every iteration? Every ten iterations? That's harder to answer.

Comment: When the interest is in prediction, people generally select $\lambda$ through cross-validation of values spread across a reasonable search range and applying standard heuristics to choose the most suitable $\lambda.$  Your generic question about balancing losses has no definite answer because ultimately *you* have to choose how best to trade off between them.  How to quantify and discover your preferences is the subject of mult-attribute value theory (MAVT).

Comment: Ensemble loss function might help, https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.01130.